# Bulk post update after changing default layout

Tags: wordpress, post, layout, bulk

I just change default layout for my wordpress "Patterns" theme. I try to find out, how I can update all posts in one go? There is over 50000 articles.

Many Thanks

Comment: can you specify what part you want to update? like meta or title or description?

Comment: In wordpress you have "change lauout" option I change this http://demos.gabfirethemes.com/patterns/2012/05/21/in-turpis-at-erat-auctor-sodales/ for this http://demos.gabfirethemes.com/patterns/2012/05/21/aliquam-tortor-vehicula-neque/ And I want to chage all post in my website to use new layout

Answer (score 0):

If you change your theme pattern, the template should work fine, for the 50k posts.

But there is conditions:
- shortcodes generated by plugins must be compatible in term of size (width)
- thumbmails sizes are correct for this layout, if not, you need to regenerate all of them

Comment: The images are fine. How to do it?

Comment: By editing options of your theme using the live customizer, you should the change immediately. Give use more details for your problem.